# how to develop my website to show a authentication window(javascript) like the netgear routers show when connected to them..?

Tags: javascript, html

`javascript or html ?`i want to add a authentication required box like the netgear routers have ?how can i code my website to do so ? [image: this is what the authentication looks like]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to follow these steps:

1)create a password file in your www folder

2)configure http.conf

Find a tutorial [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html)

Answer (score 0):

Neither. That's HTTP. Specifically, [basic auth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

While this can be done in your server side programming language (e.g. [in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) and [a Perl module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI%3a%3aAuth%3a%3aBasic)), it is usually handled by your web server. The specifics depend, of course, on which web server you are using. For example, [here are instructions for Apache HTTPD](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) and [for IIS](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/abbca505-6f63-4267-aac1-1ea89d861eb4.mspx?mfr=true).